# Parallel execution of command using Parallel::ForkManager

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, multitasking

I want to know whether my understanding is right or not for the below script/logic.

I have list of nodes and I need to run a certain command on each of the node by utilizing number of servers which I have by doing SSH to the servers, means the process should happen parallelly.

I have `node_list.txt` file which contains list of nodes:

```
node1
node2
.
.
node49
node50
```

I have defined number of servers in an array `@hosts` where I should do SSH and execute the command to each node by splitting the `node_file.txt` into equal number of parts(called `$node_list_X.txt`) in an available servers.

Once I have these files (`node_list_1.txt`,`node_list_2.txt`,`node_list_3.txt`,`node_list_4.txt`) I will be logging into each the server which is already been defined and executing certain commands on each hosts by passing `node_list_X.txt` file parallelly.

To execute this parallelly I am using `Parallel::ForkManager` Perl module.

So that, lets say in each host -

```
192.168.0.1 -> node_list_1.txt (13 nodes)
192.168.0.2 -> node_list_2.txt (13 nodes)
192.168.0.3 -> node_list_3.txt (12 nodes)
192.168.0.4 -> node_list_4.txt (12 nodes)
```

will run parallelly.

Script is below:

```
...
my @hosts = ("192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3","192.168.0.4");

open(my $node_fh, '<', $node_file)
        or die "can't open $node_file: $!";

my @lines =  <$node_fh>;

my %Files;

my $num_buckets = scalar @hosts;

my $per_bucket = int( @lines / $num_buckets );
my $num_extras =      @lines % $num_buckets;
my $path = "/home/user/vinod/test/";

for my $bucket_num (0..$num_buckets-1) {
   my $num_lines = $per_bucket;
   if ($num_extras) {
      ++$num_lines;
      --$num_extras;
   }

   last if($num_lines == 0);
   my $qfn = $path."node_list_${bucket_num}.txt";
   open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   $fh->print(splice(@lines, 0, $num_lines));
   $Files{$bucket_num} = $qfn;
}
print Dumper(\%Files);

my $command = #"defining my command here";

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
my $ssh;

DATA_LOOP:
foreach my $n (0..$num_buckets-1) {
    if( exists $Files{$n} ) {
        my $pid = $pm->start and next DATA_LOOP;

        $command_to_execute = $command." ".$Files{$n};
        $ssh = SSH_Connection( $hosts[$n-1], "user", "password" );
        $result = $ssh->capture($command_to_execute);
      
        $pm->finish;       
    }
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
undef $ssh;

#SSH Connect
sub SSH_Connection {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
                                user => $user,
                                password => $passwd,
                                master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"]
    );
    $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
    return $ssh;
}
```

Here everything works fine.

When I am defining `$pm` object, parallel process set to 5.

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);
```

Does this means at a time in a particular server (Ex:192.168.0.1) it should run 5 parallel process. Means it should take 5 nodes from a `node_list_1.txt` (out of 13) file and execute the command?

Is my understdning correct? If not, what could be the possible solution to run the command in each server parallelly with multi-threading?

Answer (score 5):

> *Does this means at a time in a perticular server (Ex:192.168.0.1) it should run 5 parallel process.*

No. P::FM doesn't know anything about servers. It manages processes, and `->new(5)` means `->start` will wait for one of the processes it created to finish before creating a new one if 5 of them are still executing.

> *what could be the possible solution to run the command in each server parallelly with multi-threading?*

Assuming you meant multi-tasking generally rather than multi-threading specifically (since you aren't using threads), create a process for each host could be done as follows:

```perl
my %children;
my $error = 0;
for my $host (@hosts) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if (!defined($pid)) {
       warn("Can't execute on $host: Can't fork: $!\n");
       next;
    }

    if ($pid) {
       ++$children{$pid};
       next;
    }

    if (!eval {
       do_it($host);
       return 1;  # No exception
    }) {
       warn("Error executing commands on $host: $@");
    }
}

while (%children) {
   ( my $pid = wait() ) >= 0
      or die("Can't wait: $!\n");

   delete($children{$pid});   
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response @ikegami. How this could be implemented in my script? Because I need to ssh to the host too.

Comment: Do whatever you want in `do_it`.

Comment: If I add `DATA_LOOP` part in `do_it` each node file will run for each server right? I mean 4*4. I'm confused.

Comment: @zdim If I iterate over the buckets then you mean to say there is no need of using `Parallel::ForkManager`. And it will loop through each host and run the command by connecting to server using `Net::OpenSSH`.

Comment: @vkk05  (I misread, so removed those two comments) --- since this code `fork`s (a child process for each server) you _can_ use your `DATA_LOOP` as is (with `P::FM` child processes) inside `do_it()`.

Comment: Using P::FM in `do_it` would be suboptimal. If you wanted to parallelize jobs on the remote machine, it would be best to use P::FM on the remote machine.

Comment: Re "*If I add DATA_LOOP part in do_it each node file will run for each server right?*", Yes

Comment: I added `do_it` sub in the code @ikegami provided like this: `sub do_it { my $host = shift; my ($command_to_execute, $ssh); my $command = "<command>"; foreach my $n (0..$num_buckets-1) { if( exists $Files{$n} ) { $command_to_execute = $command." ".$Files{$n}; print "command_to_execute on :$command_to_execute on host:$host\n"; $ssh = OpenSSH_Connection( $host, "user", "password" ); $ssh->capture($command_to_execute); }} undef $ssh; return; }` But here I could see the print statement is been printing 60 times. that means it will hit the server that many times I believe. How to sort this out?

Comment: The above comment is not about the answer. The comments are not the place to ask new comments for numerous reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run jobs on a bunch of different servers, consider a proper job queue. Perl's [Minion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion) is very nice. Various servers can connect to it, ask for jobs in various ways, and send back the results.

Comment: Looks interesting. May I know where can I get more info/examples on `Minion`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider using [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel)?

It seems to me that it directly supports what you want to do and is able to handle lots of connections in parallel, schedule then, handle errors and retry failed commands, etc.

**Update**: *But will it allow me to run jobs parallelly inside each host?*

But what do you really want to do? distribute jobs over a set of workers? In that case, brian d foy solution is probably a better option.

Anyway, `Net::OpenSSH::Parallel` was never intended for that, but yet it can do it:

```
my @hosts = ...;
my @tasks = ...;
my $n_workers = 5;

my $ossh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new;

for my $host (@hosts) {
  for my $ix (0..$n_workers) {
    $ossh->add_host("$host-$ix", host => $host);
  }
}

my $fetch_task = sub {
  my ($pssh, $label) = @_;
  if (defined (my $task = shift @tasks)) {
    $ossh->push($label, cmd => $task);
    $ossh->push($label, sub => $fetch_task);
  }
}

$ossh->push('*', sub => $fetch_task)

$ossh->run
```

Comment: Sure. But will it allow me to run jobs parallelly inside each host?